# How to run pulseaudio -D from boot

Tags: pulseaudio

I am currently setting up a bluetooth connectivity system for my garage to play music through. I have got the music playing and running smoothly, but I cannot figure out how get the pulseaudio daemon to run from startup or from a script. I'm hesitant to try random google searches since I don't want to break something important! I guess im just unsure how to proceed! any amount would help!

Here's the link/guide i used in case someone needs to take a look.

[Setup Raspberry Pi 3 as bluetooth speaker](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47708/setup-raspberry-pi-3-as-bluetooth-speaker)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using Raspbian check `systemctl list-unit-files | grep pulse`.  If you installed pulseaudio via `apt`, there should be a service available already, you just have to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the command to your `/etc/rc.local` file.

If you ever feel insecure about changes, you can backup your whole SD card to your computer's hard drive with `dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdX of=/path/filename.img` and restore it later with the vice-versa command `dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdX if=/path/filename.img`. Of course, you would have to edit them to fit your specific requirements, like device name of the SD card (sdc, sdd...) and path and filename on our computer's hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/rc.local` file add:

```
su -c 'pulseaudio --start' - pi
echo connect 00:00:00:00:00:00 | bluetoothctl
```

before the `exit 0` command.

This works if you have already paired and trusted your bluetooth device. Make sure to change `00:00:00:00:00:00` to your bluetooth device address.