# Using the Pi 3 as a Bluetooth speaker and Mic

Tags: pi-3

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi. I'm working on a home automation project that requires the Pi to act as a Bluetooth speaker and mic for a phone.
In this project the Pi basically acts like a **Bluetooth headphone with mic.**

I have a speaker with 3.5mm jack and PNP USB mic. I have followed [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47708/setup-raspberry-pi-3-as-bluetooth-speaker) guide and the audio is working just fine. Sound is choppy but its ok for now. Can anyone help me to use the mic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had any success with this?