# /tmp has been reported to be read-only filesystem

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, filesystem, pulseaudio

Environment: Up to dated rasbian.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ cat os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $
```

I would like to make my RPI to a Bluetooth speaker as I can connect it to my speaker system with HDMI. And I followed [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/48055/83579). However, it turns out that there is no audio output after I successfully paired and connected it to my phone. But `omxplayer` works fine.

After a few investigations, I found that there is something wrong with `pulseaudio`. I found those issues from syslog

```
pulseaudio[895]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create random directory /tmp/pulse-jQKTIx5u3FhO: Read-only file system 
pulseaudio[895]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock. 
pulseaudio[895]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock 
systemd-udevd[855]: Process '/usr/lib/udev/bluetooth' failed with exit code 1. 
systemd-udevd[853]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
```

I am confused that `/tmp` is writeable from shell --- both `mkdir` and `touch` works fine.

And it seems that there is nothing wrong with `/tmp`

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        30G  5.3G   23G  19% /
devtmpfs        460M     0  460M   0% /dev
tmpfs           464M     0  464M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           464M   13M  452M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           464M     0  464M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   41M   22M   20M  53% /boot
tmpfs            93M  4.0K   93M   1% /run/user/1000
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ ls -dhl /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 4.0K Mar 18 14:32 /tmp
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ cat fstab 
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=98e0451d-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=98e0451d-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $
```

I really have no idea what's going on.

#### Update:

Here comes the output of `mount` command:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=470128k,nr_inodes=117532,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=94944k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: please add the output of `ls -lah /tmp/pulse-jQKTIx5u3FhO` (it is possible that it does not exist)

Comment: @Fabian Yes, the random directory does not exist. But I don't know why: `/tmp` is `1777` which means every user should have the permission to create a directory under `/tmp`. According to the [source code](https://github.com/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/blob/master/src/pulsecore/core-util.c#L1791) there must be something wrong with `mkdir(fn,m)`. I tried to recompile pulseaudio with `-O0 -g` so I can attach `gdb` to it. However, packing a debian package ... hmmmm hard to say.

Comment: there could be an issue with the permissions of your home dir: https://askubuntu.com/questions/338382/pulseaudio-not-working-home-directory-not-accessible-permission-denied

Comment: Note that `tmpfs` and `/tmp` are not the same thing.  The former is frequently but not necessarily used for the latter.  In this case, as it is for current versions of Raspian, `/tmp` is not a `tmpfs` filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened this issue--seems similar to yours, at least the read-only filesystem part.

[Link to issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2497)

However, I'm not using pulse-audio and can stream from a connected bluetooth device using an A2DP profile.  Apparently, it's not needed and can cause issues on stretch.